# In firebase cloud functions, how do I run a scheduled onRequest call?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, schedule

I am having issues with utilizing cors inside of a scheduled firebase function, for example you have `functions.pubsub.schedule().timeZone().onRun (context=>{... }); This us due to request, responce is not available as params in the onRun function.

.onRequest((req,res),()=>{...})` pass req and res params I need to run Cors function, but unfortunately I cannot do a use onRequest function in a scheduled cloud function, instead it needs to be onRun.

Is there anything I can do to work around this?

Below is the error I received when trying to use onRequest in a scheduled cloud functions.

```
TypeError: functions.pubsub.schedule(...).timeZone(...).onRequest is not a function
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shann\Documents\KellyRecovery_Client\functions\index.js:306:10)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at C:\Users\Shann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:21:11
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Shann\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\firebase-tools\lib\triggerParser.js:75:3)
```

the overall purpose of this is to schedule emails being send on a weekly basis, using nodemailer. You need to use cors in order to send status response f the email was successful otherwise you can get duplicates or delays in receiving emails. cors needs a req and res which can be aquired from the onReqeust function call, this function is not an option on a pubsub scheduler.

So I am trying to find a workaround.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the actual problem you have, as right now it's hard to understand how we can help. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have updated my question with some more details including an error I got, thanks.

Comment: Please consider accepting one of the answers if it solves your problem to improve the visibility of the information shared in this thread.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work in GCP, you can use a CRON JOB :

https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating

Answer (score 1):

I believe you confound the use cases of the products that the Cloud Platform provides you in order to schedule event execution.

The idea behind Cloud PubSub is to decouple event creation and event execution through the use of Publisher/Subscriber queues so that you can create as many jobs as you want and be assured that at some point they will be processed in an asynchronous fashion, but it's not intended to specify when the execution will happen. [Here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/overview#scenarios) are common use cases.

Another product is Cloud Tasks which is aimed to store events created by another source until the conditions set for it's execution are meet. Although it allows fine-grained control about when the task will be ran, it's not intended for periodically scheduled jobs as every task has to be independently pushed to the queue. Nonetheless you may take a look at [this](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/tutorial-gcf) where it shows how to send email with App Engine + Cloud Functions + Cloud Tasks.

Finally, as Raphael said there is Cloud Scheduler which is most suitable option for your use case as it is meant to schedule user configured periodic event execution. I recommend you to take a look at how to [create](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/creating) cron jobs as well as [this](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-pub-sub) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/comp-tasks-sched) pages that explain key differences between all these products.